# proper way to deploy symfony project with composer

Tags: symfony, installation, composer-php, githooks

We have git hook to deploy new branches (or update old ones) for symfony 2 project to the dev server. `composer.lock` is added to git repository so that `composer install` would install same version of vendor libs. `/app/bootstrap.php.cache` is not included in git rep.

Hook steps:

1. composer install
2. ./app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
3. clear cache

## Problem

If there are database problems (changed database schema, login credentials are not working etc.) `composer install` fails on `Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file.
If switch 1-2 steps and run migrations first it would not run because vendor libs must be installed first.

## Question

How should I deploy app properly?

Comment: Have you tried the docs? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html

Comment: Take a look at Capifony. http://capifony.org/

Comment: I have been using `Capifony` for years now but few weeks ago`Magellanes` caught my attention. It is described at the link @Qoop provided.

Comment: @jperovic.. I've not noticed that before. Looks very interesting.

Comment: The docs say 'Update your vendor dependencies' and then 'Run database migrations'. In my case it does not work as you can see. I found out about Capifony today but right now I just want to fix my script and move on.

Comment: Can you paste the entire error message? Which version of symfony2 are you use?

Comment: It complains about database problems, so for instance if you have database credentials in parameters.yml try to delete/change them and run composer install. Symfony 2.5.2.